# How to retrieve a particular list from serialzed form data sent to controller through jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have to replace particular part of page on button click event. For that in java script i have a call to `ajax` where `serialzed` form data is send to `controller`. How can i retrieve particular list  from form data. After retrieving another object should be added to list and sent to `jsp`. Can any one please let me know how can I do it.

```
$.ajax({    
        type:"POST",        
        url: "",    
        data: $('form#regist').serialize(),     
          success: function(success) {    

          }   
       });
```

Comment: Each object in list corresponds to one table in jsp. Every table will have delete button when clicked on delete button corresponding table should be deleted. Let me know how this can be implemented.

Comment: ask another question

Answer (score 1):

something like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String retrieveList (Object object ModelMap map) {
    return "success";
}
```

`object` is the `modelAttribute` to map, should be same what has serialized in the form, or you can say, same as your `commandName` of this `JSP`.